# Ubuntu 14.04 64Bit : Cursor lag when mouse cursor changes?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, sata, dell-inspiron

I'm facing the exact same issue as mentioned in the [link](https://superuser.com/questions/492685/cursor-lag-when-mouse-cursor-changes) but on Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit.

### Problem Facing:

- Mouse pointer freezes for around 300 ms whenever the cursor icon changes:

  - On hovering from text field into back to mouse pointer.
  - When crossing the window border, cursor changes to re-size cursor into back to mouse pointer.

It's happening all the time and within every application (Excessively in Chromium, Firefox)

There is an another problem of right click context is very slow but I don't know whether it's related or not.

### Things I have tried but with no success:

- Changing desktop environment to Unity/cinnamon/gnome-flash-back
- Changing my graphics drivers to Xorg/AMD proprietary
- Decrease/Increasing touchpad/mouse pointer acceleration and sensitivity.

### System Configuration:

Dell N4110

[image: Configuration]

### Update 1

I have installed indicator-multiload and observed high iowait even with CPU % close to 7-8. Using iotop I have observed 2 Specific process namely kworker and jdb are causing high io operation. I have no idea what these processes are doing.

### Update 2

I have looked into /var/log/syslog and the content is as follows:

```
Jan  1 00:43:48 bolt kernel: [ 9091.210590] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40000 action 0x6 frozen
Jan  1 00:43:48 bolt kernel: [ 9091.210604] ata1: SError: { CommWake }
Jan  1 00:43:48 bolt kernel: [ 9091.210610] ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
Jan  1 00:43:48 bolt kernel: [ 9091.210621] ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 27
Jan  1 00:43:48 bolt kernel: [ 9091.210621]          res 40/00:ff:80:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jan  1 00:43:48 bolt kernel: [ 9091.210627] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jan  1 00:43:48 bolt kernel: [ 9091.210635] ata1: hard resetting link
Jan  1 00:43:53 bolt kernel: [ 9096.571351] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Jan  1 00:43:58 bolt kernel: [ 9101.220139] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
Jan  1 00:43:58 bolt kernel: [ 9101.220154] ata1: hard resetting link
Jan  1 00:44:03 bolt kernel: [ 9106.585077] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Jan  1 00:44:04 bolt kernel: [ 9107.145217] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jan  1 00:44:04 bolt kernel: [ 9107.195250] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jan  1 00:44:04 bolt kernel: [ 9107.195259] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
Jan  1 00:44:04 bolt kernel: [ 9107.195421] ata1: EH complete
Jan  1 00:44:17 bolt kernel: [ 9120.143473] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x50000 action 0x6 frozen
Jan  1 00:44:17 bolt kernel: [ 9120.143485] ata1: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake }
Jan  1 00:44:17 bolt kernel: [ 9120.143491] ata1.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
Jan  1 00:44:17 bolt kernel: [ 9120.143500] ata1.00: cmd ec/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 17 pio 512 in
Jan  1 00:44:17 bolt kernel: [ 9120.143500]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jan  1 00:44:17 bolt kernel: [ 9120.143504] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jan  1 00:44:17 bolt kernel: [ 9120.143512] ata1: hard resetting link
Jan  1 00:44:22 bolt kernel: [ 9125.504263] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Jan  1 00:44:26 bolt kernel: [ 9129.200981] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jan  1 00:44:26 bolt kernel: [ 9129.248292] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jan  1 00:44:26 bolt kernel: [ 9129.248459] ata1: EH complete
Jan  1 00:44:39 bolt kernel: [ 9142.131168] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40000 action 0x6 frozen
Jan  1 00:44:39 bolt kernel: [ 9142.131181] ata1: SError: { CommWake }
Jan  1 00:44:39 bolt kernel: [ 9142.131187] ata1.00: failed command: CHECK POWER MODE
Jan  1 00:44:39 bolt kernel: [ 9142.131198] ata1.00: cmd e5/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 3
Jan  1 00:44:39 bolt kernel: [ 9142.131198]          res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jan  1 00:44:39 bolt kernel: [ 9142.131204] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jan  1 00:44:39 bolt kernel: [ 9142.131213] ata1: hard resetting link
Jan  1 00:44:44 bolt kernel: [ 9147.495976] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Jan  1 00:44:48 bolt kernel: [ 9151.304687] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jan  1 00:44:48 bolt kernel: [ 9151.351255] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jan  1 00:44:48 bolt kernel: [ 9151.351413] ata1: EH complete
Jan  1 00:45:01 bolt CRON[7231]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245699] ata1.00: NCQ disabled due to excessive errors
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245706] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40000 action 0x6 frozen
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245711] ata1: SError: { CommWake }
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245714] ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245721] ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 15
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245721]          res 40/00:ff:ff:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245724] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jan  1 00:47:16 bolt kernel: [ 9299.245728] ata1: hard resetting link
Jan  1 00:47:21 bolt kernel: [ 9304.614593] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Jan  1 00:47:26 bolt kernel: [ 9309.263429] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
Jan  1 00:47:26 bolt kernel: [ 9309.263445] ata1: hard resetting link
Jan  1 00:47:31 bolt kernel: [ 9314.624287] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Jan  1 00:47:32 bolt kernel: [ 9315.576458] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jan  1 00:47:32 bolt kernel: [ 9315.623445] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jan  1 00:47:32 bolt kernel: [ 9315.623455] ata1.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
Jan  1 00:47:32 bolt kernel: [ 9315.623629] ata1: EH complete
```

I have ran the SMART data and self-test with no failure. So, is my HDD working is fine ?

Are there problem with SATA cable ? How I can confirm without using any other hardware.
Please suggest what else I can try or a solution.

Please suggest what else I can try or a solution.